# Which types should I register with my IOC container for Umbraco ContentService to be instantiated?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, umbraco

One of the classes in my Umbraco project depends on `IContentService`. I'm trying to provide an `IContentService` to this class with an IOC container.

Here is how I'm registering `IContentService` with my IOC (Autofac)

```
builder.RegisterType<Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService>().As<IContentService>();
```

However, `Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService` requires these constructor parameters:

```
public ContentService(IDatabaseUnitOfWorkProvider provider, RepositoryFactory repositoryFactory, ILogger logger, IEventMessagesFactory eventMessagesFactory, IPublishingStrategy publishingStrategy, IDataTypeService dataTypeService, IUserService userService);
```

Autofac gets stuck because it doesn't know about any of these types yet. Here's a stack trace:

```
Exception Details: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with
'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService' can be
invoked with the available services and parameters:Cannot resolve parameter
'Umbraco.Core.Persistence.RepositoryFactory repositoryFactory' of constructor 'Void
.ctor(Umbraco.Core.Persistence.UnitOfWork.IDatabaseUnitOfWorkProvider, Umbraco.Core.Persistence.RepositoryFactory,
Umbraco.Core.Logging.ILogger, Umbraco.Core.Events.IEventMessagesFactory, Umbraco.Core.Publishing.IPublishingStrategy,
Umbraco.Core.Services.IDataTypeService, Umbraco.Core.Services.IUserService)'.
```

Which types should I register with Autofac so that my ContentService can be instantiated?

Comment: I believe `PetaPocoUnitOfWorkProvider` is good enough to satisfy the dependency on `IDatabaseUnitOfWorkProvider`

Comment: I would just do something like this:
`container.Register(x => UmbracoContext.Current);`
and then get the service through that: `.Application.Services.ContentService`.
I'm not sure instantiating a new contentservice yourself would be a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I solved this particular problem. Thanks to [Claus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/336105/claus) for the help.

I need to use `RegisterInstance()` ([docs here](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#instance-components)) instead of `RegisterType<T>()`

```
public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // Register the components we need resolving with Autofac
    builder.RegisterInstance(applicationContext.Services.MemberService).As<IMemberService>();
    builder.RegisterInstance(applicationContext.Services.ContentService).As<IContentService>();

    // ... Configuration for dependency resolution here ...
}
```

The reason for this is that Umbraco creates an instance of `ContentService` and configures it correctly. Autofac needs to be told to use this instance instead of trying to create it's own.